# How to create a post-method in an UmbracoApiController to send an Email using smtp

Tags: .net, api, model-view-controller, umbraco

I'm Trying to create a post method in UmbracoApiController but can't figure it out.
However, I did create one using SurfaceController. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What is it you're stuck on? Make sure you reference the `HttpPost` from `System.Net.Http` and not `System.Web.Mvc`

Comment: Second @mark what are you stuck on? or you got nothing at all and would like a full working example.

Comment: Yeah please, a full example. using entity framework

Comment: Send an email and gets it saved in my db.

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have created it by SurfaceController, you should be able to create it by UmbracoApi almost the same way. I guess you might use a wrong URL.
For Surface controller you usually use this routing:

```
/umbraco/surface/{controllername}/{action}/{id}
```

When for API you should use something like this url:

```
/Umbraco/Api/Products/GetAllProducts
```

it means you should replace surface with api.
If it is not the case, can you please share your code. It can be really helpful.